# Why are my prefetched scripts not being used? (webpack)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webpack, loadable-component

I'm trying to prefetch scripts so that I can render (prefetched) React components the user will navigate to faster. My scripts are being prefetched but they don't seem to be used. When I go to another page (e.g. Look), the Look bundle is fetched *again* and the prefetched bundle is not being used at all.

I've posted two screenshots of the headers of each request.The prefetch request has a different `Accept` value in its header (requests [made by webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules)). The `Cookie` value also differs, I believe this is something Google Analytics related but I don't think this is the issue.

Whilst typing this I've noticed the Preview/Response tab in Chrome says "Failed to load response data" (see first screenshot) so I checked Firefox and there the responses are both the same but I'm guessing this might be an indicator of what's wrong.

TL;DR: Why are my prefetched scripts not being used?

I'm using [`@loadable/component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loadable/component) for prefetching components, example code:

```js
import loadable from '@loadable/component';
import React from 'react';

const LoadableComponent = loadable(
  () =>
    import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "Look", webpackPrefetch: true */
      '../containers/Look'
    ),
  {
    fallback: <div />,
  },
);

const LookLoadable = () => <LoadableComponent />;

export default LookLoadable;
```

[image: Preview of request in Chrome]

[image: The headers of the prefetch]

[image: The headers of the request (that shouldn't be made) when user navigates to Look page]

Comment: what version of webpack are you using ?

Comment: @Taki webpack version "4.41.2"